# SciPy fails to build from source on Mac under CPython 3.9/PyPy on Intel & M1 Macs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cpython, pypy

I have virtualenvs on both an Intel Mac running Catalina and an M1 Mac running Ventura and a friend has tried on an Intel Mac running Monterey.

I am following the build from source instructions from the scipy docs:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/building/index.html which state:

xcode-select --install (make sure Xcode command line tools are installed)

brew install gfortran openblas pkg-config
pip install scipy --no-binary scipy

https://handloomweaver.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/scipy_m1_cpy3.log [CPython 3.11 Ventura M1 Mac]

https://handloomweaver.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/scipy_m1_py3.log [PyPy 3.10 Ventura M1 Mac]

https://handloomweaver.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/intel.log [CPython 3.9 Intel Monterey]

https://handloomweaver.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/scipy_intel_cpy3.log [CPython 3.11 Intel Catalina]

You will see that in every case they fail to build and for different reasons even though I've followed the instructions.

Summary, they all say:

Either:

```
../scipy/meson.build:159:9: ERROR: Dependency "OpenBLAS" not found, tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake
```

Or:

```
../../numpy/meson.build:207:4: ERROR: Problem encountered: No BLAS library detected!
```

Or:

```
../meson.build:82:0: ERROR: Unable to detect linker for compiler `gfortran -Wl,--version`
```

Or:

```
Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
```

(last one while building ninja .whl)

pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.

It's okay if there is an exact .whl but if there isn't and in my case I am trying to build on PyPy where there is no .whl available. But as evidenced, it isn't an M1 problem or a PyPy problem. You can't pip build from source SciPy currently on a variety of CPython or PyPy versions on two different backend architectures and three different OS versions.

Am I not getting something or should I file a bug?

Comment: Can you include relevant content in your question as regular text, not as huge download links?

Comment: I've summarised the main error in each. Apologies

Comment: Does this depend on Fortran or BLAS? If so you may need to install more (Homebrew?) dependencies.

Comment: As per the question I have installed what docs.scipy.org specify to do: brew install gfortran openblas pkg-config so BLAS and fortran are installed

Comment: What does `pkg-config openblas --modversion` show? This is the basic part that must work before buildling scipy/numpy from source.

Comment: `pkg-config openblas --modversion
Package openblas was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'openblas.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'openblas' found.` **[on the M1]**